# TFS turn local path into UNC path?

Tags: tfs

I am using the WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment task that can be downloaded from the Microsoft Marketplace. For the source location, I want to use

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip

However, this translates to a local path where the build agent resides, but not a path on the target machine. I want to turn the local path into a UNC path by replacing the initial 'c:\' with '\*servername*\c$\'. Is this possible?

This article about release variables does not tell me anything about how to actually use the variables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the binaries to the server first by using the Windows Machine File Copy task.

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. I was just wondering if there was another way.